# How to use Morphia to findAndModify with a sorted search query?

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, deprecated, morphia

I am using Morphia 1.6.1 and this is my actual code:

```
final Query<Entity> query = datastore.createQuery(Entity.class)
    .field("status").equal(Status.OPEN)
    .order(Sort.ascending("lastUsed"));

final UpdateOperations<Entity> updateOperations = datastore
    .createUpdateOperations(Entity.class)
    .set("lastUsed", ZonedDateTime.now());

final Entity entity = datastore.findAndModify(query, updateOperations);
```

The only problem is that .order() is @Deprecated. So I need to find another way to do this. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on 1.6.1, you can happily use that method.  Once you move to 2.x, the way that modify operations are done and how options are passed changes a bit so you'll need to do a bit of rework regardless.  (There's an option to keep using the legacy API that's deprecated in it's entirety and will be removed soon.  maybe in 2.4.)

2.x is a complete rethink of that API in to what is intended to be a more reasonable, usable set of interfaces.  So far folks seem happy with it.  I'd highly recommend an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently trying to get it run with 2.2.1 but I'm still having issues. Would you do it with an aggregation? Like here
``` 
final Aggregation<Entity> aggregation = datastore.aggregate(Entity.class)
        .match(Filters.eq("status", Status.OPEN))
        .set(AddFields.addFields().field(
            "setLastUsed",
            new Expression("$set lastUsed", ZonedDateTime.now())
        ))
        .sort(Sort.sort().ascending("lastUsed"));
```
Still this gives me an object of the type dev.morphia.query.internal.MorphiaCursor which is deprected again, if I call .execute()

Comment: Take a look at the [modify()](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/javadoc/dev/morphia/query/Query.html#modify(dev.morphia.query.experimental.updates.UpdateOperator,dev.morphia.query.experimental.updates.UpdateOperator...)) method on `Query`.

Comment: Also, depending on how your app and data is situated, you might want to explore the [legacy()](https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.2/javadoc/dev/morphia/mapping/MapperOptions.html#legacy()) configuration on the `Mapper`.  It will preserve the pre-2.0 behavior on things like queries and entity mapping.  But if the new/modern options are working, definitely use those.

Comment: My team just agreed on using the deprecated order method of version 1.6.1. So we're using the code of my original post.